# Ajax call insert

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have 2 ajax calls one to insert data, one to get data. Together with the functions for select and insert. the console log of the ajax call select is empty. However, when i check phpmyadmin the correct value is there.
If i start the game again, there will be 1 value (from previous game) but the score of the actual game isn't there. Until I start the game again. And so on. Does anyone know why the values are in my sql but the ajax call says it's empty?

What I understand from it. There's a score via ajax and in php it will get into the part "Check json" it sees json isn't empty so it goes to InsertScore().
The second ajax is cast but this time it doesn't have json so it will get to the method "GetScores".

The insert happens always before the select so the last score should be seen, I don't understand why it doesn't do that.

**Ajax call insert:**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Database.php",
     dataType: "json",
     data: { json: jsonData }                    
});
```

---

__ajax call select:__

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Database.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        stageRef.$("var1").html(obj[0].x);
        stageRef.$("var2").html(obj[0].y);
        stageRef.$("var3").html(obj[1].z);
        stageRef.$("var4").html(obj[1].a);
        stageRef.$("var5").html(obj[2].b);                  
        stageRef.$("var6").html(obj[2].c);
    }                  
});
```

---

__php insert:__

```
function InsertScore($obj) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (x, y) VALUES('" . $obj['score'] . "','" . $obj['naam'] . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

---

__php select:__

```
function GetScores() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $scoresArray = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $scoresArray[$i]['x'] = $row['x'];
        $scoresArray[$i]['y'] = $row['y'];
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($Array);
}
```

---

__check json:__

```
if (isset($_POST['json'])) {
    $x= json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
    InsertScore($x);
} else {
    GetX();
}
```

---

Comment: `stageRef.$("txtTopscoreNaam1").html(obj[0].Naam);`. What does this line mean?

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: oh, it's a adobe edge animate file, it's just plain weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the ajax-calls synchronous:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Database.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { json: jsonData },
    async: false 
});
```

This way the 'select'-call will wait for the 'insert'-call to finish.